# Why does apt-get remove leave package-installed cron files lying around?

Tags: cron, package-management, packaging

Is there a good reason why `apt-get remove` leaves installed cron files in place where an `apt-get purge` or `apt-get remove --purge` is actually required to  completely remove them?

Example files may be:

- `/etc/cron.d/<packagename>`, or
- `/etc/cron.hourly/<packagename>`

The man pages and everything else I've seen seems to indicate that only configuration files should remain after a `remove` command, and `purge` will only remove those configuration files in addition to the package.

If these are considered configuration files, then why? Is it possible to have customised (/configured) versions of these files based on the installation?

Comment: I'm not sure you are appropriately phrasing the question.  It sounds like you are eliciting an opinion.  If you find this to be a bug, why not go to the appropriate distribution bug site and report it?

Comment: @mdpc I'm trying to determine the reason for this behaviour - if I'm missing something. I don't know much about packaging at all but I found this behaviour odd and would like to know why it is this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those files are considered configuration files. Generally, (at least) everything in `/etc` is considered a configuration file in Debian. That's why it takes a `purge` to remove them. The reason they are configured configuration files is that anything that the system administrator is reasonably expected to customize or edit should be considered a configuration file, and that generally includes anything in `/etc`, and especially a `crontab` file.

Comment: It's also why cron scripts will have a line `[ -x /usr/bin/whatever ] || exit 0`: this way you won't get error messages if the package is removed and the cron script still exists in e.g. `/etc/cron.daily/`.